# More than one method 'ConvertFromString' on type '' is compatible with the supplied arguments

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

My CsvBool converter is

```
public class CsvBool : BooleanConverter
    {
        public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return string.Empty;
            
            var boolValue = (bool)value;

            return boolValue ? "YES" : "NO";
        }

        public override string ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        {
            if (text == null)
                return string.Empty;

            if (text == "YES")
                return "true";
            else
                return "false";   
        }
    }
```

When writing the file, everything works as expected. All true booleans are written as
`YES`

While trying to read the csv file, i get the error

```
More than one method 'ConvertFromString' on type 'CsvBool' is compatible with the supplied arguments.
```

The error is type of `CsvHelperException` within the first loop

What am i doing wrong here?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
   using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))

     csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.RemoveConverter<bool>();
     csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<bool>(new CsvBool());

     csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvProduct>();
     var CsvProducts = csv.GetRecords<Product>();
     foreach (var CsvProduct in CsvProducts)
     {

     }
```

and here is my mapping class

```
public class CsvProduct : ClassMap<Product>
    {
        public CsvProduct()
        {
            Map(m => m.Active).Name("ActiveColumn").TypeConverter<CsvBool>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `public override string ConvertFromString` seems strange for a `BooleanConverter`. Shouldn't it return a `Boolean`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ConvertFromString` needs to return an `object` instead of `string`.  Since you marked it as return `string`, it now sees both the original `ConvertFromString` from the `BooleanConverter` which returns an object and your `ConvertFromString` which returns a string.

```cs
public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
{
    if (text == null)
        return string.Empty;

    if (text == "YES")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

FYI, there is already a `TypeConverterOption` that will do what you are looking for.

Your can either set it individually on the `ClassMap`

```cs
Map(m => m.Active).Name("ActiveColumn").TypeConverterOption.BooleanValues(true,false,"YES").TypeConverterOption.BooleanValues(false,false,"NO");
```

Or globally on the `TypeConverterOptionsCache`

```cs
csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<bool>().BooleanTrueValues.Add("YES");
csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<bool>().BooleanFalseValues.Add("NO");
```